# window.solana.request doesn't trigger phantom on some browsers

Tags: web3.js

When calling window.solana.request() in a function, in some browsers phantom opens and I can validate the transaction, and on some browsers nothing happen.

window.solana.connect() works properly and opens phantom, even on browsers where request() doesn't work.

Does anyone knows why is this behaviour happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't really guess why, I think it might have to do with browser compatibility but try out this code, I believe it might work for you.

```
const getProvider = async () => {
    if ("solana" in window) {
      await window.solana.connect(); // opens wallet to connect to

      const provider = window.solana;
      if (provider.isPhantom) {
        console.log("Is Phantom installed?  ", provider.isPhantom);
        return provider;
      }
    } else {
      document.write('Install https://www.phantom.app/');
    }
};

window.onload = () => {

    getProvider().then(provider => {
        console.log('key', provider.publicKey.toString())
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
    });

}
```

from the original post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989348/solana-adding-sollet-phantom-wallet-connect-to-my-website-steps

Comment: i understand you code, but connect() works properly, only request() doesn't work on some browsers.